# Calculating Combinations for a Grid

Tags: algorithms, puzzle

Bit of an odd question, but bare with me.

Lets say I have a 5x5 grid, in which each element (or tile, if you like) functions like a boolean, where it can be either on or off.

What I am looking for, is the algorithm to calculate the amount of combinations.

To help this, during generation, each element is only toggled once, so cannot be switched on, then off again, and a random number of elements are toggled each time.

What I am looking for is a way to calculate the maximum amount of combinations there could be for this type of setup.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to know how many combinations of On-Off tiles there are?

Comment: Have you tried calculating it by hand for a $1 \times 1$, $2 \times 2$, and $3 \times 3$ grid and noticing the pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $25$ tiles in the grid, each can be in one of $2$ states, so there are $2^{25}$ total possible setups.